# firefox 5.0: status bar disappeared despite "status 4 evar" extension

Tags: firefox, statusbar

My status bar disappeared somehow in the past few days. I have Status 4 Evar installed.

I tried disabling all my add-ons except Status 4 Evar, and the status bar is *still* gone.

Help! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bar we used to call the "Status Bar" is, as I understand it, now known as the "Add-On Bar".  It can be toggled one of two ways:

- Via Menu:  Firefox -> Options -> Add-On Bar
- Via Shortcut:  Ctrl + /

Comment: I was going to say "What does that have to do with my problem or with Status 4 Evar", but then I remembered having gone through the View Toolbars menu and seeing Add-On Bar unchecked, and not thinking much of it because I was looking for the status bar, not any "add-on bar". I must have hit Ctrl-/ by mistake (I often use "/" for quick-find). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the *Status for Evar* page, the addon works with Firefox Firefox 4.0 - 7.0a1. I suggest uninstalling the addon, then putting it back in. Try [creating a new profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles), and then installing your addon there. This will clear any old settings that may have been tampered with. Upgrading your version of Firefox may have erased some settings that you had before.

Comment: It wasn't the upgrade for Firefox; I did that last week and it worked fine.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried using a new profile?

Answer (score 1):

I chose the "nuclear option" (uninstall Firefox 5.0 completely, including customizations, reinstall) and it worked.

Something in the customizations must have caused problems, because when I uninstalled/reinstalled Firefox 5.0, it still had the same issue.

Comment: If this was your solution, remember to mark it as the answer, so others with this issue will see it.

Comment: @Simon -- I will, but SO makes me wait 2 days.

Comment: ...and perhaps for good reason. (this Q in particular)

Comment: This is not SO though.

Comment: s/SO/StackExchange